# Removing duplicate range of 2d list

Tags: python, list

I have a program that reads an excel file to get hours that employees work divided by the pay period.

I have a class called Employee that has name, idNumber and hours as attributes.

For example Bob's hours are

```
[['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 45.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 48.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 45.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 48.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 46.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 32.5]]
```

index 0 and 1 are the same because it is week 1 and 2 or payroll. The problem is I'm trying to remove index 2 and 3 and keep the rest.

My code is currently this

```
for f in range(len(employeeList)):
    currenthours = employeeList[f].hours
    newHours = []    
    for l in range(len(employeeList[f].hours)):
        if currenthours[l:l+1][:] == currenthours[l+2:l+3][:]:
            newHours = currenthours[l+2:][:]
            print(employeeList[f].name + " has duplicates")
        else:
            employeeList[f].hours = currenthours
            break
        employeeList[f].hours = newHours
```

print(employeeList):

```
Name: Bob
Employee Number: 966
Hours: [['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 45.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 48.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 45.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 48.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 46.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 32.5]]
,
Name: Nick
Employee Number: 586
Hours: [['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 32.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 24.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 32.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 24.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 43.5], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 29.0]]
,
Name: Frank
Employee Number: 233
Hours: [['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 40.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 40.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 40.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 40.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 40.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 24.0]]
,
Name: Jo
Employee Number: 123
Hours: [['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 44.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 47.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 44.0], ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 47.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 32.0], ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 24.0]]
```

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over a list with `for index in range(len(my_list))` in python, especially if you use `index` only for accessing the element of the list. Iterate over items in the list directly with `for item in my_list`. If you _really_ need the index too, use `for index, item in enumerate(my_list)`

Comment: Please also provide a [mre]. What is `employeeList`? What list gets the extra items added to it? Where do you add these items? What is wrong with your code? Please take the [tour] and see [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary constructor to obtain unique combinations while keeping the original order.  To make the sublist usable as keys of the dictionary you can convert them to tuples and then convert the resulting keys back to lists:

```
hours = [['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 45.0], 
         ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 48.0], 
         ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 45.0], 
         ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 48.0], 
         ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 46.0], 
         ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 32.5]]

hours = [*map(list,dict.fromkeys(map(tuple,hours)))]

print(hours)
[['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 45.0], 
 ['(29/11/2020 to 12/12/2020)', 48.0], 
 ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 46.0], 
 ['(13/12/2020 to 26/12/2020)', 32.5]]
```